# Javascript method to download generated file without replacing the url

Tags: javascript, file, url, download, reload

I am working on generating a text & sql file when the user clicks on <kbd>Download</kbd> from the query displayed in a text area on the same form. I have written the following code. But the issue is that, the URL is being replaced and the entire page is automatically refreshed after the download. Due to this, continuing operations won't be able to be performed.

**Javascript Method**

```
function download() {
      var element = document.createElement('a');
      var filename = document.getElementById("filenameInput").value;
      var text = document.getElementById("runquerytext").value;
      element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + text);
      element.setAttribute('download', filename);

      element.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.appendChild(element);

      element.click();

      document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can download the generated file without reloading/ changing the uri will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want someone to download the file without refreshing the page, I would suggest you to use an iframe. The page is redirecting because a  "a" tag redirects the page upon clicking it. So to solve that generate dynamic iframe tag with javascript or an image tag. For example:

```
    function download() {
     var element = document.createElement('iframe');
     var filename = document.getElementById("filenameInput").value;
     var text = document.getElementById("runquerytext").value;
     element.setAttribute('src', 'data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8,' + text);
     element.setAttribute('download', filename);
     element.style.display = 'none';
     document.body.appendChild(element);
    }
```

Comment: will this permit the user to download the file without refreshing /replacing the url?

Comment: I modified the code as `element.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/octet-stream' + text);` but the url is replaced with `http://localhost:8080/controllers/veditor?filenameInput=me.txt&filetype-combo=1&downloadFileBtn=` and the entire page is refreshed.

Comment: Why don't you do it within an image tag? like <img src="data:application/octet-stream,data" /> or load it in an iframe?? Would that help? and yeah that would refresh the page because you're making an link to that file. Don't put a link, use  an invisible iframe or img tag

Comment: Since the form is dynamically generated using js at runtime, how exactly can i use an img tag?

Comment: function anything(){
var a = document.createElement("img");
a.setAttribute("src", "data:application/octet-stream,data");
//  append a somewhere to do something
}

Comment: Could you kindly edit your answer with this idea and let me know. Would be much better.

Comment: Sorry, But the entire page is refreshed again

Comment: Is the url being changed again? if the page layout is refreshed i've again edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry. No luck yet. They are being refreshed.

Comment: Hey, can you tell me the full scenario or just display me the updated code?, I just tested it and my pages are not being refreshed.